# JavaScript filter - What to return from jQuery filter callback method?

Tags: javascript

What do I need to return from my jQuery filter callback method in order to properly define the function, regardless if the result of the filter applied to my variable is not used after invocation of the filter method?

```
var results = [];
var filterResult = 0;

$(elem).each(function(){
    results.push($(this).val().trim().toLowerCase())
});
var string = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();

results.filter(function (r) {
   if(r == string)
       filterResult = filterResult + 1;
   return r;   //<-- what needs to be returned for this callback to be properly defined
});
```

Comment: What you are using here is just basic javascript `.filter()`, from which you should return true/false. If true, the item gets included in the results set, if false, it gets omitted. It should be noted that this method is non-destructive, and thus, should be assigned to a variable if you want to do anything with it.

Comment: return r == string;

Comment: Thank you, so the result of the if condition that results in the action performed is the value to be returned.     I don't believe this will incur any side effects because I do not use the value below that line.  I am am merely refactoring code.

Comment: @Vahe The boolean expression, yes.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a *new* Array by applying a function to each element of an existing array, and only including that element if the function returns `true`.

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

For example:

```
var arr = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3];
var positive = arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0;
});
// num now contains: [1,2,3]
```

From your code snippet, that doesn't really seem like what you're trying to do. Rather it seems like you're trying to derive a single value from the elements of an array. In that case, what you want is [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a):

```
var count = results.reduce(function (total, currentItem) {
    if (currentItem == string) {
        return total + 1;
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}, 0);
```

The second argument there (0) is the starting value of `total`.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed response!    For my case, would I be better off iterating the array and just increment the "filterResult" variable?  It seems to be all that is required to perform the intended operation in my code.